# R group_by %>% full_join losing NA records

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider these two data frames:

```
t1<-data.frame(Time=1:3,Cat=rep("A",3),SomeValue=rep("t1",3))
t2<-data.frame(Time=c(1,2,3,1,3),Cat=rep("A",5),Id=c(1,1,1,2,2),SomeOtherValue=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

In my application, I need to do a full join and work with missing records/values. Doing partial full_join on subsets (grouping var) works, but I lose my missing values when I try the unfiltered approach.

This will give me 6 records

```
t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% filter(Id==2) %>%  full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))
t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% filter(Id==1) %>%  full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))
```

This will give me 5, where the missing entry (NA values) of Id==2 and Time==2 is gone:

```
t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))
```

My understanding of group_by is that it groups by variable(s), and continues with all my following mutation,mapping etc on each group. Is it supposed to behave in this way?

Comment: `group_by` is not the problem. You got 5 rows because you are joining based on `Time` and `Cat`.  You can see that `t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))` and `t2 %>% full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))` give the same result

Comment: In `t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% filter(Id==2) %>%  full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))`, you got missing values because after using`filter` you actually subsetted `t1`, this results in a completely different data frame

Comment: I don`t understand this. Can you elaborate on what you mean by the statement that I have subsetted 't1' . If I do the same in SQL I will get 6 records.

Comment: `t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% filter(Id==2)` or `t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% filter(Id==1)` and `t1` are different. You should not expect to have the same output after full)joining them with `t2`

Comment: At what point have I subseted t1? I have explicitly subsetted t2 by means of filtering. What I am saying is that the union of the two joins (i.e the two outputs) does not make up the unfiltered one. I was expecting that. Indeed they are different, that is the whole point. I need everything from t1 and everything from t2. full_join: return all rows and all columns from both x and y. Where there are not matching values, returns NA for the one missing.

Comment: In t2 %>% full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat")) I will have a "hit" for Time=2 and Cat=A, so this make sense to return 5 records. However, when I do group_by, there is only a "hit" for Id=1. The join behaves in the same manner with or without group.

Comment: I inverted `t1` and `t2` in my previous comment. Sorry for this. Sure, with `full_join` you want everything from `t2` and `t1` but __since you merge by `Time` and `Cat` (not `Id`)__, there is no mistake neither in `t2 %>% group_by(Id) %>% full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))` nor in `t2 %>% full_join(t1,by=c("Time","Cat"))`. In both scripts, the full join is right, that is why I pointed out that `group_by` is not the problem. it is all about the `by` argument in `full_join()`

Comment: Id has nothing to do with the join clause, or any other variable not found i both tables. What I am expecting is that group_by is effectively subsetting and doing two full_joins. I am saying that group_by %>% full_join should NOT equal full_join withot grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading documentation properly, I finally found the section that states that groups are ignored for the purpose of joining. ?full_join

Comment: Good job working it out! Happens to me all the time after I post here -- I feverishly scramble to find the answer before the rest of the world does.